# How to get the 3rd element of an Arraylist as the sum of first two elements in an ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am pretty new to the programming world, Kindly help me in solving this solution.

Kindly consider that suppose I have x and y values. I need to add this to an arraylist and z is a third element Z's initial value is zero and from next iteration onward z's value becomes the sum of  ((x[1] - x[0])+ (y[1]-y[0]))?
How to add values to z and how to get the sum of z?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You can add x values and y values in arraylist of integer or any type and then do like this,

```
int xSum, ySum, totalSum;
ArrayList<int> zSumList;

zSumList = new ArrayList<int>;

zSumList.add(0,0);

for(int i = 1; i < numberOfTimes;i++)
{
    xSum = x[i] - x[i-1];
    ySum = y[i] - y[i-1];

    totalSum = xSum + ySum;

    zSumList.add(i,totalSum);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Basically when executing a formula I will get x and y values after every minute and based on that i have to find the z value using the formula I said before. Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Consider like this after every minute i will get new x and y values. array will be like [x(0), y(0), z(0), x(1), y(1), z(1), x(2), y(2), z(2).............] where z(0) will be zero and z(1) will be squareroot of (x(1)-x(0))+(y(1)-y(0))